# Grabbing one character after the Nth pattern match - PERL

Tags: perl, matching

i have a sample file that is structured like below, and i would like to perform some operations on it :

```
1112283569;AOEEEEAOAO.;300012299419;0030000302;ALLE;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;7914944
1112283569;AOEEEEAOAO.;300012;;;;AAAAA299419;*;;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66
1112283569;AOEEEEAOAO.;*;*;;0.00;0.;;;;;;;;;00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149
*;CON;*;0030000302;ΑLLEO;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00
;CONE:;*;*;;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;;;79149449.66;0.00
```

I m trying to come up with a solution for this. I need to read a file that looks like the one above,
delimited by ';' and i need to run a check on the character after the 3rd delimiter on each line at a time. It will not be in a 
static column, so i need some way to capture the character after the nth delimiter (;), i might be able do this with a regex (i think.)

Ie, for the above output :

Line 1 - Doesnt meet condition
Line 2 - Doesnt meet condition
Line 3 - Meets condition
Line 4 - Doesnt meet condition
Line 5 - Meets condition

Finally it would output something like :

```
1112283569;AOEEEEAOAO.;*;*;;0.00;0.;;;;;;;;;00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149
;CONE:;*;*;;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;;;79149449.66;0.00
```

(Only the lines where the first character after the third delimiter is *)
I ve found this type of regex, but i m not sure it would apply in this situation? :

```
   /\%(^\%([^ ]* \)\{6\}\)\@<=.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply by `split`-ing on `;`, then checking the first character of the required field.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $char = '*';
my $nth = 3;

my $file = 'data_delim.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file -- $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    my @fields = split ';', $line, $nth+1;

    if ($fields[$nth] =~ m/^\Q$char/) {
        print $line;
    }   
}
```

The `$nth` above stands for "Nth" specification, `3` in the question example.  We tell [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to take only the needed N+1 elements, by passing the last argument. The `\Q` escapes the `*`, denying it its special meaning. See [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).  You can pick only the field needed for the check and shorten the loop body to

```
print $line if (split ';', $line)[3] =~ m/^\Q$char/; # or /\*/
```

I suspect that there may be more involved in the question and keep all preceding terms.

For the input file `data_delim.txt` with shown input this prints

```
1112283569;AOEEEEAOAO.;*;*;;0.00;0.;;;;;;;;;00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149
;CONE:;*;*;;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;79149449.66;0.00;;;79149449.66;0.00
```

I used sample input and output as I didn't fully understand the description.  I can only hope that this is a correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: is there a way to reverse that if statement, basicly - if the condition doesnt apply, print the line, i tried a !=~, got no error, but clearly did not work. I also tried if not. Basicly, dont print the line if there's a * after the 3rd delimiter.

Comment: @onlyf To revert the `if` statement use either `unless` instead of `if` (which I don't recommend because of its ugliness) or use `!~` instead of `=~`.

Comment: @onlyf  As PerlDog says, you can use `!~`, so the `if` evaluates true if there is no match.  You can also negate it explicitly, `if (not  /regex/)` (or use `unless` as PerlDog says).

Comment: Thank you both. I really appreciate the help.